# Android extends class

Tags: java, android, android-activity, extends

I'm developing an `Android` app and my classes relationships are like this:

[image]

On `FacebookClass` I can't use methods like `findViewById`, because I don't access `BaseClass` objects (super super class, I mean), it's like if I can't use `Activity` methods.

Aditional informations:

- `BaseClass` extends `android.app.Activity`;
- `BaseClass` and `SocialNetworkClass` are abstract classes;
- My intention with this hierarchy is produce less code (and reuse code).

Could anyone help me, please? Thanks!!

Comment: 'I can't use methods like findViewById'. Are you sure? This method is Public method of Activity so I believe you can. From OOP. You can access Protected/Public members from based classes.

Comment: Could you include a screenshot or logcat of you being unable to use `findViewById`? With given structure, it should work.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's about the findViewById. The log: http://pastebin.com/xCepbaNk

Comment: I read somethings, @LocHa, about the "calling method on super super" doesn't work.

Comment: @Marius, the log: http://pastebin.com/xCepbaNk

Comment: You should post relevant Activity code. By relevant I mean the code that clearly causes the NPE. Also, include relevant information HERE, for reasons, refer to guide on how to ask questions.

Comment: I just use "LinearLayout lnItens = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_add_avatar);".
Like I said, it's on the "FacebookClass", that doesn't extend Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first, to make it clearer what these classes are, they should be named appropriately:

```
BaseActivity extends Activity

SocialNetworkActivity extends BaseActivity

FacebookActivity extends SocialNetworkActivity
```

Provided your hierarchy is like that posted above, you absolutely will have access to methods like findViewById() -- everything an `Activity` instance would have access to (unless SocialNetworkActivity or BaseActivity declares any of these methods as final).

Your problem is a null pointer exception in findViewById(), which just means you haven't set your content view in the activity, and are trying to find views when no layout has been inflated. Ensure that you've set your content view before calling findViewById().